# C# JSON how to read a specific value with unknown Parentname

Tags: c#, json

i want to read the Date "datum" form this json string in to a List of DateTime:

```
{
  "Neujahrstag": {
    "datum": "2016-01-01",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Karfreitag": {
    "datum": "2016-03-25",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Ostermontag": {
    "datum": "2016-03-28",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Tag der Arbeit": {
    "datum": "2016-05-01",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Christi Himmelfahrt": {
    "datum": "2016-05-05",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Pfingstmontag": {
    "datum": "2016-05-16",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Tag der Deutschen Einheit": {
    "datum": "2016-10-03",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "Reformationstag": {
    "datum": "2016-10-31",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "1. Weihnachtstag": {
    "datum": "2016-12-25",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "2. Weihnachtstag": {
    "datum": "2016-12-26",
    "hinweis": ""
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to do that.

I use the following code to get the json string and parse it but i have no idea how to get to a List or Array.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = wc.DownloadString("https://feiertage-api.de/api/?jahr=2020&nur_land=MV");

                JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);

                MessageBox.Show(DateTime.ParseExact(result.First.First.First.First.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
            }
```

Is there an easy way to do this or do i have to write a costume deserializer for this kind of json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be to create a class for your inner objects:

```
public class Data
{
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string HinWeis { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your JSON into a `Dictionary<string, Data>` and fetch each `Datum` from the values:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString("https://feiertage-api.de/api/?jahr=2020&nur_land=MV");

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(json);

    foreach (var kvp in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.Datum.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01
2020-04-10
2020-04-13
2020-05-01
2020-05-21
2020-06-01
2020-10-03
2020-10-31
2020-12-25
2020-12-26
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't see that before i post my solution. This looks better to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Orko No worries. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend @RoadRunner's solution since it's the clean and correct way.
Still I'll leave the quick n dirty way here for reference

```
// ...
JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var child in result.Children())
{
    var holidayName = child.Path;
    var dateString = child.First["datum"].Value<string>();
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve my problem for others to use.

```
            var publicHolidays = new List<DateTime>();

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = wc.DownloadString("https://feiertage-api.de/api/?jahr=2020&nur_land=MV");

                var result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

                IEnumerable<JToken> dates = result.SelectTokens("$..datum");

                foreach (String s in dates)
                {
                    publicHolidays.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(s.ToString().Substring(0, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }

            }
```

Not sure if this is a smart solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution

```
foreach (var item in JObject.Parse(json).Values())
{
    DateTime date = item.Value<DateTime>("datum");
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```